# How to connect a 12V electromagnet to 220V power adaptor

Tags: power-supply, voltage, ac, dc, electromagnetism

I'm not very familiar with electronics, but I want to create a basic automatic pet feeder for my outdoor dog house. My idea is simple: a wooden box with a floor that drops at a set time, controlled by an electromagnetic lock and a standard Plug-in Timer. Since there's no Wi-Fi, I'm keeping it simple without any 'smart' systems.

Questions:

Should I use a lock that releases on power-on or power-off?

- Power-on release: [Amazon link](https://www.amazon.se/-/en/Electric-Magnetic-Lock-Electromagnetic-Cabinet/dp/B07L2YFZW3)
- Power-off release: [Amazon
  link](https://www.amazon.se/-/en/ML60-Electromagnetic-Electronic-Fail-Proof-Electrical/dp/B08Y5TWFT5)

Can I just cut the connector and solder it onto a power supply adapter like this one? [Amazon link](https://www.amazon.se/-/en/GreenSun-Adapter-100-240V-Transformer-Maximum/dp/B086X1MTZY)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I use a lock that releases on power-on or power-off?

You have a couple of considerations:

- The lock should last much longer if it is only powered for a short while. Energise-to-release would be more power efficient.
- What do you want to happen if the power fails? Keep the door locked (prison mode) or release the lock (emergency exit mode).

> Can I just cut the connector and solder it onto a power supply adapter like this one?

That would be fine - but not with that power supply. Down low in the Amazon ad for the lock it states:

> Electrical Parameters: DC 12V 2A

The PSU you have chosen is only rated at 12 V, 1 A.

By the way, 12 V × 2 A = 24 W. If you have that powered for 24 hours (which I know you won't in your application) the power consumption would be 24 W × 24 h = 576 Wh = 0.576 kWh so it would cost you > half a unit per day. That's just another little bit to add to somebody's electricity bill!

Comment: Thanks, I truly appreciate your answer, and now I feel more confident. :) I think a power cut = giving food would be my best option. I'm only delaying mealtime from 4 pm to 9-10 pm. I'd rather have them get food early than starve. Also, thanks for the heads up; it's my electricity bill :) But what I'm doing now is taking the car back and forth during my break on the occasion I have to work night/evening. That's not free either.